# J2me detecting first start of application

Tags: java, java-me, midp

My question is simple how can I recognize first start of application? I think it can be accomplished by saving some value in RMS and reading it when app starts and decide what to do.

But isn't there simpler solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is'nt a simpler method as far as I know, but that's very easy anyway;

```
    public static boolean isFirstRun() {
        RecordStore rs = null;
        try {
            rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore("myAwesomeRecordStore", false); //check
            return false; //record store exists, so it's not our first run
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //RecordStoreNotFoundException, but we need to catch others anway
            try {
                rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore("myAwesomeRecordStore", true); //create
            } catch (Exception e1) {}
        }
        finally {
            if (rs != null) try {rs.closeRecordStore();} catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        return true; //so, record store did not exist and it was created (if no error occured (there shouldn't be any errors anyway))
    }
```